# Is the udasi sampraday vaishnavs or shaivites or other?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, vaishnavism, shaivism

The udasi sampraday is founded by Sri Chandra Baba the son of guru nanak and  is linked to the four kumaras parampara.

They worships 5 devatas: ganesh, surya, shiva, shakti and vishnu. I know they believe in both nirgun and sargun brahman and they where tripundra tilak.

But I have met many of the members of the udasi sampraday from raman reti, gokul and most if not all of those bhaktas only have Sri Krishna as their ishta devata, while still engaged in their traditional worship of 5 devatas.

So what exactly is their philosophy regarding brahman and all the devatas?

Do they see the panch devatas as the supreme and equal or do they hold the view that Vishnu or Shiva is the ultimate source and is supreme? Or is nirgun brahman the supreme therefor implying that moksha is merging with brahman instead of attaining a spiritual body and eternally residing in vrindavan with Sri Krishna.

What are their core vedic scriptures that they subscribe to ?

And is their a specific vedantic perspective that they interpret these scriptures, like advaita, dvaita, vishista advaita, dvaita-advaita Vedanta?